# WordPress Permalink 404

Tags: permalinks, themes, errors

I have a problem with Permalink since from version 4.4, from frontend when members try to insert post shows 404 when click submit button, can't insert post only show 404, When i changed to Plain in WordPress settings from %postname% to Plain work fine.

```
<form id="submitForm" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

$post_data = array( 
                    'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
                    'post_type' => $dox_options['ad_set']['type']['base'],
                    'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
                    'post_content' => $_POST['description'],                                
                    'post_status' => 'pending',
                    'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    'ping_status' => 'closed'                           
                );                  
                /* insert post */
                $ad_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data, $post_error );

if ($post_error == false) {

                /* required files */
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

                $files = $_FILES['attachment'];

                if ($files) { 

                    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                            $file = array(
                                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                            );  
                        }

                        $_FILES = array("attachment" => $file);
                        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {                                
                            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $ad_id, array(), array( 'test_form' => false ) );
                            if ($attach_id < 0) { $post_error = true;  }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form fields to have more unique names, specifically, `title`. [This is an issue which was introduced when `title` was made a public query var in 4.4](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35115). This is seen as a bug, and will eventually be fixed, but it's always safer to prepend any vars with a unique string to prevent these problems.